# Default to lib=stdlibc++ for clang++ on Mac OS Mavericks with Xcode?

Tags: c++, macos, clang++

I'm running MacOS X Mavericks with Xcode 5.1.1 including the command line tools.
I'm compiling simple C++ programs using clang++ supplied with Xcode, the version info is:
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)

What I find is that if I try to run the following command

> clang++ -o hello.out hello.cpp

I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
___cxx_global_var_init in hello-2ad0da.o
"std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
___cxx_global_var_init in hello-2ad0da.o
"std::cout", referenced from:
_main in hello-2ad0da.o
"std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
_main in hello-2ad0da.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I change the command to

> clang++ -o hello.out -stdlib=libstdc++ hello.cpp

I don't get any errors.

Is there a way to make "-stdlib=libstdc++" the default for clang++, either with some configuration setting or some environment variable? Also, just for my information, why do I get the error?

Comment: It's just a simple C++ program to print "Hello, World". I can post the source if you want, but notice that it works if I specify stdlibc++. The only library it includes is <iostream>

Answer (score 4):

`MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` may be what you are looking for.

`export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8` should make `clang` to default to `libstdc++` instead of `libc++`.

Comment: Caused this error on my system: ```CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.2.3/share/cmake/Modules/Platform/Darwin.cmake:76 (message):
  CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is '10.8' but CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT:

   ""

  is not set to a MacOSX SDK with a recognized version.  Either set
  CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to a valid SDK or set CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to
  empty.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.2.3/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:36 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (project)```

Comment: @kilojoules: Should be self explaining. `export CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)`.

Comment: `xcrun --show-sdk-path` returns nothing. I get the same error message after running both export commands. Is there something I should download?

Comment: @kilojoules: `xcrun` is an Xcode utility. `export CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/` may work too.

Comment: OK thanks for all the help. I installed XCode and `xcrun --show-sdk-path`  works now. When I run my cmake file with these settings, the 10.8 target still isn't found. Now I get this message: ```
  CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is '10.8' but the matching SDK does not exist
  at:

   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk"

  Instead using SDK:

   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk".
```

Comment: I tried following these instructions https://github.com/phusion/traveling-ruby/tree/master/osx but in XCode -> Developer -> Plaforms -> Mac Platforms -> Developer -> SDKs I only have the 10.10 and 10.9 SDKs

Comment: I created a new question regarding this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359687/xcode-10-10-download-10-8-sdk

Answer (score 3):

**Before OS X 10.9.x**:

> The default was `libstdc++` (using clang++ -o hello.out hello.cpp)
>   would have worked fine.

**OS X 10.9.x**:

> The default is `libc++` (as you know the including flag
>   -stdlib=libstdc++ links your project correctly).

Since you're trying to compile code that uses symbols that are not within the design of the newer `LLVM libc++` standard library you receive errors. As for changing the default that `clang` uses you'd likely have to patch it's [ToolChains.cpp](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Driver/ToolChains.cpp?view=markup) [(docs)](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) with something such as:

```
-     DAL->AddJoinedArg(0, Opts.getOption(options::OPT_stdlib_EQ), "libc++");
+     DAL->AddJoinedArg(0, Opts.getOption(options::OPT_stdlib_EQ), "libstdc++");
```

- [Further Reading](http://libcxx.llvm.org/)