# download 10.8 sdk on OSX 10.10 / set MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8

Tags: xcode, macos, sdk

It would be very useful to me to successfully `export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8`. When I do that, I get this message:

```
CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is '10.8' but the matching SDK does not exist at: "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/‌​SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk" Instead using SDK: "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/‌​SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk".
```

I tried following these instructions github.com/phusion/traveling-ruby/tree/master/osx but in XCode -> Developer -> Plaforms -> Mac Platforms -> Developer -> SDKs I only have the 10.10 and 10.9 SDKs. How can I successfully `export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8`?

Comment: FYI: The SDK defines the newest version of the OS that you want your app to support; the deployment target defines the oldest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile for Mac OS X 10.8 (even for 10.4!) using the 10.10 SDK.

`export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8` is all you need, ignore the (useless) warning.